# inline bash for-loops and greps

Tags: bash, for-loop, terminal

-Edit- This isn't a duplicate because I'm using one file to compare another everything I found on SO is looping through one file without an input file to compare.

A list of *filenames.csv* looks like this:

```
"aaabbccdd-3ksdfs"
"asdfdsbh-kkdkdsd"
"asdfds123221sssa"
```

I have another *onelongstring.txt* that that only has one massive string:

```
asfdsafsdafs//sdfasdschasdjs//akdasdfshcie//asdfdsbh-kkdkdsd...
```

What I would like to know is if each of the values in *filesnames.csv* exist in *onelongstring.txt*.

I tried something like this:

```
for i in filename.csv; do grep $i onelongstring.txt > countiffound.txt
```

But it wasn't working, then I realized if I just tried to do a loop like this:

```
for i in filename.csv; do echo $i;done
```

My output would just be the name of the file rather than each line of the content.

Is there a way to do this on the `bash` command line (osx) instead of having to write a script in `bash`?

Comment: Can you add proper input/output and remove the `...` from the `onelongstring.txt`

Comment: Are the strings between `//` supposed to be found in their entirety or do you look for a solution which finds a match in a substring anywhere between `//` separators? (Why are you using such a ludicrous file format anyway?)

Comment: Have you googled `iterate over lines of file bash`?

Comment: Writing a one-liner and writing a script is basically the same thing. In a one-liner you can't use line breaks but that's a superficial constraint as far as Bash is concerned. The text in a script can be pasted at the command line and vice versa.

Comment: I don't think this Q is a duplicate of [Looping through the content of a file in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1521462/looping-through-the-content-of-a-file-in-bash), since that Q involves one file, but this question has *two* files.

Comment: I don't think this should be marked as duplicate because that's not only about looping through the file, but also finding each string. This is a one-liner: allfound=1; onelongstring=$(cat onelongstring.txt); while read line; do if [[ ! "//$onelongstring//" =~ ^.*\/\/${line//\"/}\/\/.*$ ]]; then allfound=0; break; fi; done <filenames.csv; echo $allfound;

Comment: Pending reopen, try this: `tr -s '/' '\n' < onelongstring.txt | grep -f - filename.csv > countiffound.txt`

Comment: hey @chowpay if you replace your for loop with the while loop in the answer that people were linking you to, then that fixes your problem

Comment: @HansZ it got too confusing, ended up writing a python script that just looked through all the variables in one file and checked if it existed in another. I was hoping there was just a simple in line bash I could do instead. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is mostly in cleaning and separating the strings in the files. So, using awk with your data but with `...` removed from `onelongstring.txt`:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {
    a[$0]
    next
}
gsub(/^"|"$/,"")&&($0 in a==0) { print $0 }
' RS="(//|\n)" onelongstring.txt filenames.csv
aaabbccdd-3ksdfs
asdfds123221sssa
```